# unknown type error in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, cinder

What is going on?

```
#include "MyClass.h"

class MyOtherClass {
  public:
    MyOtherClass();
    ~MyOtherClass();

    MyClass myVar; //Unknown type Error
};
```

Suddenly when I include the .h and write that var Xcode gives me tons of errors... and also the unknown type error.

How can it be unknown when the .h is included right there?

Here is the NodeButton.h file which would correspond to the MyClass.h in the example

```
#pragma once

#include "cinder/Vector.h"
#include "cinder/gl/gl.h"
#include "cinder/gl/Texture.h"
#include "cinder/Color.h"
#include "cinder/ImageIo.h"
#include "cinder/Timeline.h"
#include "cinder/app/AppBasic.h"
#include "cinder/App/App.h"

#include "Node.h"
#include "CursorMano.h"

using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;
using namespace is;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<class NodeButton> NodeButtonRef;


class NodeButton  : public Node2D 
{
    public:
        NodeButton (CursorMano *cursor, string imageUrl, bool fadeIn = false, float delay = 0.0f);
        virtual ~NodeButton ();

        //methods
        void update( double elapsed );
        void draw();
        void setup();

        //events
        bool mouseMove( ci::app::MouseEvent event );

        //vars
        CursorMano      *mCursor;
        gl::Texture     mImageTexture;
        Anim<float>     mAlpha = 1.0f;
        bool            mSelected = false;

    private:
};
```

And here are the contents of CursorMano.h which would correspond to MyOtherClass.h in the example.

```
#pragma once

#include <list>
#include <vector>

#include "cinder/app/AppBasic.h"
#include "cinder/qtime/QuickTime.h"
#include "cinder/gl/Texture.h"
#include "cinder/Vector.h"

#include "NodeButton.h"

using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;

class CursorMano {
    public:
        CursorMano (AppBasic *app);
        ~CursorMano ();

        void    mueveMano(Vec2i);
        void    update();
        void    draw();
        void    play(int button);
        void    reset(int button);

        Vec2i   mMousePos;
        NodeButton                  mButtonCaller; //this gives the unknow type error

    private:
        AppBasic                    *mApp;
        gl::Texture                 mFrameTexture;
        qtime::MovieGl              mMovie;
        int                         mIdButton;
};
```

Comment: What are the contents of `MyClass.h` ? Also the spellings of `MyOtherClass` and its ctor-dtor are not matching!

Comment: We need more code to help out with this.  Can you show us the full contents of MyClass.h and the full contents of this header?

Comment: it will be mostly because of constructor and destructor spelling change

Comment: MyClass.h exists as it's being included in my main app. Ok I'll include the .h file.

Comment: So, there is the code... anyone?

Comment: @Pier: Show your *real code*, Contrived examples are usually faulty in ways other than the actual problem

Comment: @Als I've edited my question with real code. You want the .h where the error happens too?

Comment: There you have it, the real .h files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a circular dependency of your header files.

`NodeButton.h` defines `NodeButton` class which `CursorMano.h` needs to include so that compiler can see definition for `NodeButton` but `NodeButton.h` itself includes `CursorMano.h`.

You will need to use forward declarations to break this circular dependency.

In `NodeButton.h` you just use an pointer to `CursorMano` so You do not need to include the `CursorMano.h` just forward declare the class after the using namespace declarations.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace is;

class CursorMano;
```

Comment: Ok, but then how can I reference both classes from each other?

Comment: @Pier: Forward declare `CursorMano` in NodeButton.h (write `class CursorMano;`) and remove `#include "CursorMano.h"` from NodeButton.h.

Comment: Ah, just as I was typing my answer :)

Comment: @ktodisco: And you get a +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a result of the circular dependency between you two header files (`NodeButton` includes `CursorMano` and `CursorMano` includes `NodeButton`).  Try removing the `#include "CursorMano.h"` in NodeButton.h and add `class CursorMano;` before your `NodeButton` declaration.